# I Can't Write A Triangle Pattern in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Here's the code

```
for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
    for (int j = 5; j>=i; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = i; k>0; k--) {
        System.out.print(k + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output I want to get is:

```
            1
          2 1
        3 2 1
      4 3 2 1
    5 4 3 2 1
  6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Instead, what I get is:

```
      1 
     2 1 
    3 2 1 
   4 3 2 1 
  5 4 3 2 1
```

Can you explain to me the reason and tell me how to solve it, in a beginner-friendly way?

Comment: Do you understand the code you have already written?

Comment: Have a look at the output you want. How many spaces do you need before each line?

Comment: Try `System.out.print("  "); // 2 spaces` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints to help you solve this:

1. Read your code and make sure you understand what it is doing.  (If someone else wrote it for you, ask the author to explain!)  You can't fix code (properly) if you don't understand what it is doing ...
2. Look at your expected output, and count the number of spaces at the beginning of each line.
3. Look at your actual output, and count the number of spaces at the beginning of each line.
4. What is the difference between the corresponding counts?
5. What is the pattern in the differences?
6. The fix is a simple change in one line of your code.  If you have done steps 1 and 5 correctly, it will be "obvious" what you need to change.

**UPDATE** - My mistake.  @Bohemian points out that there are two differences.  There are two lines that need to be changed if you also want the number of lines of output to be the same.

(But the real point of this answer is to help you to work it out for yourself ...)

Comment: Maybe more lines than 1: If OP wants to print *6* lines, OP will probably want to replace `5` with `6` too.

Comment: Ah ... good point.  Yes, there are two differences.  I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand the problem and what exactly you are doing with your code.

These were my steps for solving this:

- Try to understand the output.
- Count the spaces in between everything to see if there's some pattern.
- Look at the expected output and compare it to yours.
- Make adjustments based on that.

If you're having a hard time to solve a problem, try to break down the problem into smaller parts. Then write it in pseudocode in notepad, so you have a better understanding of what you're actually doing. For example:

For each iteration I have to print X amount of spaces, and print Y

- iteration 1 : print x spaces, print y
- iteration 2 : print x spaces, print y
- and so on..

I'm sure you can figure it out 
Here is the solution:

```
    for (int i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
        for (int j = 6; j>i; j--) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for (int k = i; k>=0; k--) {
            System.out.print(k+1 + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```